# How do I only select records in a table that have all the values from another table?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008

This is a hard question to word, but is pretty simple when explained a little more.

I have two tables:  Standard_Test{StandardID int, TestID int} and Test{TestID int}

Standard_Test: http://i51.tinypic.com/2u60ket.png

Test: http://i51.tinypic.com/2bbqxj.png

I need to select a list of StandardID's that have all of the TestID's from the Test table associated to it.  In the example above, this query would only select StandardID 5 & 6 because they both have TestID's 1,2,3(all of the TestID's from Test) associated with it.

It sounds simple, but I have not been able to come up with the proper query.  Thanks in advanced!

Comment: The term for this type of query is [relational division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: Thanks Martin!!! That article did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relational division.  Google for that term and you should find all the info you need.

Comment: That was the ticket!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try this, it should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT st.StandardId
FROM Standard_Test st JOIN Test t
ON st.TestId = t.TestId    
GROUP BY st.StandardId
HAVING COUNT(st.TestId) = (SELECT COUNT(TestId) FROM Test)
```

Comment: My co-worker came up with the same answer.  The problem is that the Test table is a temp table generated based on user input. This table could just have records 3 & 4. That's why the count won't work, they actually need to match

Comment: @kamojoe: I edited my post. Now comparison in HAVING clause is made counting IDs on Test table... it should be what you need now.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for any number of rows in Test. (It assumes that a given TestId only appears once in Test -- it is the primary key, right?)

```
SELECT st.StandardID
 from Standard_Test st
  inner join Test te
   on te.TestID = st.TestID
 group by st.StandardID
 having count(te.TestId) = (select count(*) from Test)
```

Comment: Small note : it does not work if the number of rows in Test is zero.  In that case, the logically correct result would have to be "all recorded standardID's", but they would probably need to be drawn from a table not included here (table standard_test will probably be empty too).

Comment: The Test table is a temp table generated based on user input.  This table could just have records 3 & 4.  That's why the count won't work, they actually need to match.

Comment: Actually, it should work. The inner join from Standard_Test to Test produces one row for each Standard_Test.TestID found in Test, and then you compare that with the count of how many rows it would have found if it had joined on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The Below Code will Work To find your Requirement.
Check it out.
Here Tab1 = Standard_Test And tab2 = Test

Declare @Test Int

Declare @Tab table
(
    Stand int
)

Declare @Cur Cursor
Set @Cur = CURSOR For
Select standardID From tab1
Group by standardID

Open @Cur
 Fetch Next
 From @Cur into @Test

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin
        If Exists (Select 1
        From tab2
        Where estID not in (Select testId From tab1 Where StandardID = @Test))
            Begin
                insert into @Tab
                values(@Test)
            End
        Fetch Next
        From @Cur into @Test
    End
```

Close @Cur
DEALLOCATE @Cur

Select * From @Tab